# insertar ceros de la izquierda de una variable en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

estoy extrayendo los datos de la fecha actual:

`

```
$fechaSys = date('Y-m-d');
$day = date('d', strtotime($fechaSys));
$month = date('m', strtotime($fechaSys));
$year = date('Y', strtotime($fechaSys));
```

pero cuando los paso en el insert(el dia y mes) :

```
`insert into table () values ( $day , $month  )`
```

todos los días o meses que vienen con `0` al comienzo no graba el `0`:

ejemplo en ves de grabar `01` me graba `1`

el tipo de dato es un `char(2)` para dia y mes.

alguien sabe la solucion???

Comment: tipo de dato donde almacenas el día?

Comment: char(2), tambien probe con varchar (2) o int...

Comment: Mysql provee tipos de datos para trabajar específicamente con fechas y tiempo como pueden ser `DATE`, `DATETIME` o `TIME` por ejemplo, deberías utilizar este tipo de datos en lugar de utilizar char o varchar. Puedes revisar la documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: @Xerif si, pero no es ese mi problema. tengo una columna `día` que almacenara un tipo de dato `integer de 2 caracteres`, pero cuando el primer carácter es un `0`, por defecto no lo graba y solo graba el segundo carácter.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo La cuestion que yo me hago es por que tienes un campo dia? Y un campo mes? A priori sin una justificacion esto aparenta ser un mal diseño de la base de datos, lo que equivale a futuros dolores de cabeza injustificados. Por eso te comentaba lo de los tipos de datos.

Comment: @Xerif estoy de acuerdo contigo, lamentablemente el negocio ya esta funcionando así. y para normalizar ahora no es el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estupidez mía,

A simple vista, eran las comillas en las variables `php` cuando realiza el `insert...`

Corregido:

`insert into table () values ( '$day' , '$month'  )`

Answer (score 2):

Declara tu columna de tipo `INT`, y agrégale la propiedad `ZEROFILL`, [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)
 mas información.

```
dia INT(2) zerofill
```

Si ya tienes la columna con tipo `CHAR` y con datos almacenados, vas a requerir modificar el tipo y agregar el atributo, hazlo de este modo:

```
ALTER TABLE tuTabla MODIFY COLUMN tuColumna INT(2) ZEROFILL;
```

Con lo anterior por ejemplo si insertas tu día así:

```
INSERT INTO demo(dia)
VALUES
(2);
```

Al hacer un `SELECT` obtendrás lo siguiente

```
dia
02
```

O bien puedes directamente hacer un `INSERT` así:

```
INSERT INTO demo(dia)
VALUES
(02);
```

El resultado también será:

```
dia
02
```

> La propiedad `ZEROFILL` completa con `0` a la izquierda el campo hasta llegar a su longitud establecida, para este ejemplo la longitud es de 2.

- [Ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a4b84e4eda585c63d55f2521933ad7b)

Comment: y si la variable viene con valor 12 ? agregaría 012 ?

Comment: no @FranciscoAcevedo si estableces que la longitud de la columna INT sea de 2 nada más, entonces aunque escribas 012, solo se registraría 12, pero si pones 9 o 09 entonces si lo registra con un 0 a la izquierda

Comment: voy a probar y te comento.

Comment: soluciono mi problema, pero igual me gustaria verlo por php el tema, algo raro pasa alli , ya que la variable viene con "01" de comienzo, no entiendo el porque lo guarda con "1"

Comment: Te comprendo, cuando tenga solución a esa duda la anexaré a esta respuesta